# lapply function to remove a list of objects

Tags: r, garbage-collection, lapply

I want to remove (rm) a list of objects on R. I use rm(object) for deleting it but how this can be donne to a vector? I want to use lapply function, let's say:

```
a = c(1,2)
b = c(3,4)
all = c(a,b)
lapply(all, FUN=rm)
```

But I got the message "must contain names or character strings". Any hints?

Comment: Try `rm(a, b, all)`

Comment: or `rm(list=c("a", "b", "all"))`.

Comment: Thanks lmo that works (both work but I need something like lmo solution)